# Date Diff - Parse Today's Date to capture the end of the fiscal year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Trying to come up with a way to use today's date to return a value I can use in a DateDiff function.

DateDiff (Month, Sales_Date, **the end of our fiscal year using today's date**)

Our fiscal year starts 4/1 and goes through 3/31

Any date (from getdate()) on or before 3/31 I would use the '3/31/' + the value of the getdate's year.

Any date (from getdate()) on or after 4/1 I would use '3/31/' + the value of the getdate's year + 1.

The end result will give me the number of months from the date of the original sale date to the end of the current fiscal year

Example
Today's date is 6/18/20, so the last parameter in the above DateDif formula would be 3/31/2021

I will be using the column in the below code:

```
Select g.sales_month,g.fiscal_year as FY, g.Sales_Type,v.region, sum(g.FY_Total) as FY_Total
from sales_FY g JOIN dbo.dimsummary AS v ON g.sales_id = v.sales_id
group by g.sales_Month, g.fiscal_year, v.Region, g.Sales_Type
```

Example:

[Picture of the end result using Excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9z32.png)

Comment: The syntax of data functions is completely different depending on the database engine. I've spotted some `dbo.`'s out there so I presume yours is SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using SQL Server

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results, including edge cases, much easier to solve than word problems.

Comment: @AaronBertrand. I pasted a picture of the end result using Excel. Hopefully, that helps. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract 3 months and extract the month.  That gives you the month of this month in the fiscal year.  Then subtract this value from 11 or 12 (I'm not exactly sure which is better for "number of months left"):

```
select 11 - month(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
```

Comment: Hello,

I tested your code and it was not the results I expected. It looks like it returns the number of months between today's date and the end of this current fiscal year. But, it does not give me the difference between the original sales date and the end of this fiscal year which is what I am after using the DATEDIFF function. Sorry if I explained it poorly in my OP. Thanks

Comment: The replace `getdate()` with the date you want.

Comment: Thank you for the post